# Swift 4 Codable Realm Object Subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable

trying to switch some of my codebase over to Swift 4's new nifty `Codable` protocol. My setup looks something like this:

```
class Base: Object, Codable {

    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var timestamp: String = ""

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "_id"
        case timestamp = "timestamp"

    }

}

class User: Base {

    dynamic var name: String = ""

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        try super.init(from: decoder)

    }

}
```

I have a base realm object class that conforms to `Codable`, and a subclass of `Base` that also has it's own coding keys. I override `init(decoder:)` on the `User` subclass to map my additional coding keys, then call `super.init(decoder:)` to map `Base`'s coding keys. However, once I override `init(decoder:)` I get the following errors:

- **required initializer 'init()' must be provided by subclass of 'Base'**
- **required initializer 'init(realm:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Base'**
- **required initializer 'init(value:schema:)' must be provided by subclass of 'Base'**

I'm not sure what the correct way is to go about fixing these issues.

Comment: Inheritance between RealmObjects is not supported

Comment: Looks like inheritance between objects should be supported: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance

Answer (score 4):

You cannot override `init()` or other initializers of Realm `Object`. You can use convenience initializer instead. Then you cannot call `super.init(from:)`, so define a method that decodes superclass' properties like `Base.decode(from:)`.

See following code sample:

```
class Base: Object, Codable {
    dynamic var id: String = ""
    dynamic var timestamp: String = ""

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case timestamp = "timestamp"
    }

    func decode(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.timestamp = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .timestamp)
    }
}

class User: Base {
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case timestamp
        case name = "name"
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()

        try decode(from: decoder)

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override just one initializer of a class. If you are going to override, do it for all of them. If you don't really use or care about the other initializers just at least call `super.<respective init>` in them.
For `init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema)` and `init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema)` compiler is going to complain that it doesn't know what RLMRealm, RLMObjectSchema and RLMSchema are. So import Realm besides RealmSwift.

Answer (score 0):

As I just answered on [another question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021808/reference-types-subclassing-and-changes-to-swift-4-codable-encoder-decoders/48830785#48830785) whilst you may be able to use your subclass as a Codable type with Katsumi's advice above, you may run into another gotcha.

**You cannot have collections of `Base` as a reference type that contain subclass instances and have that collection survive Codable. It will only decode as `Base` instances.**

Polymorphic persistence appears to be *broken by design*.

The bug report [SR-5331](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5331) quotes the response they got on their [Radar.](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=32911973)

*Unlike the existing NSCoding API (NSKeyedArchiver), the new Swift 4 Codable implementations do not write out type information about encoded types into generated archives, for both flexibility and security. As such, at decode time, the API can only use the concrete type your provide in order to decode the values (in your case, the superclass type).*

*This is by design — if you need the dynamism required to do this, we recommend that you adopt NSSecureCoding and use NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver*

I am unimpressed, having thought from all the glowing articles that Codable was the answer to some of my prayers. A parallel set of Codable structs that act as object factories is one workaround I'm considering, to preserve type information.